# JQuery attr selector to string, stored as a variable, then passed into another JQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use a JQuery selector to grab an elelement if it is clicked, check to make sure it has an appropriate class name (in this case jobtype), and if so, use its name attribute value as a selector, to hide() classes with values that are the same of the first selectors name attribute value.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    $('fieldset.workexperience input').on('change', function() {
        // var jtaa = {"bit" : "Business Information Technology",
        //          "cs" : "Customer Service",
        //          "dev" : "Developer",
        //          "eng" : "Engineer",
        //          "mgr" : "Manager",
        //          "ocm" : "Organizational Change Management" };
        if ($(this).hasClass('jobtype')) {
            $($(this).attr("name")).hide();
        } else {

        }
    });
```

The var jtaa has keys and values.   The keys represent the different possible "name" attrs. I would like when one is clicked, if its name is eng, then the JQuery selector should be `$(.eng).hide()`.  When I type directly in the console, it works, however, directly from here, it errors out.

Comment: Try something like this: `$('.' + $(this).attr("name")).hide();`.

Comment: what is syntax of an actual name value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('fieldset.workexperience input').on('change', function() {
        // var jtaa = {"bit" : "Business Information Technology",
        //          "cs" : "Customer Service",
        //          "dev" : "Developer",
        //          "eng" : "Engineer",
        //          "mgr" : "Manager",
        //          "ocm" : "Organizational Change Management" };
        var obj=$(this);
        if (obj.hasClass('jobtype')) {
            $('.'+obj.attr("name")).hide();
        } else {

        }
    });
```

Notice the period `.` concantenation to the selector
Also you might want to consider adding a not null check to make the code robust..

Comment: I tried making a temp variable and concatenating it prior to insertion, but that failed, must have had something off,   Thanks.   What would be the purpose of checking if it is not null?

Comment: if you have a control with class jobtype but it doesnt have a name attribute on it then you will end up running a selector like this $('.') which is incorrect